# Extract text from 2 columns using Google Vision Api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I have an image with 2 columns each column contains some text when try to use API it returns text horizontally from both columns in the same line is there a way to get each column separately.

I tried this code but not working correctly

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

req = {
"image": {"source": {'filename': path}},"image_context": {    "crop_hints_params": {"aspect_ratios": [ 0.5 ]},                      "language_hints":["ar"]  }, 

}
resp = client.annotate_image(request=req)
out_text = resp.full_text_annotation.text
print(out_text)
```